# Ubuntu 18.04: graphics card driver fails

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, brightness

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and the installation process went very well but when trying to change the brightness of the screen and I was unable to do that so I opened Software and update center to install graphics card driver and I found two proprietary drivers and one is nouveau X.ORG (this was enabled by default) so I chose to install the latest and the recommended one (Nvidia driver 390 as you can see in the picture)
[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36Wo0.jpg)
so after successfully installing the driver I rebooted the system but nothing was changed, I still unable to change the brightness and also can't change between the Intel graphics and Nvidia using the Nvidia X server configuring program so I deleted the driver and tried manually installing it from Nvidia website but I got the same result with no luck but when I tried to change the installed driver from software and update center I got a new option saying continue using manually installed driver and the other options were disabled (see the picture) [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3Veg.jpg)so I had to remove the installed driver using the terminal (I did this using purge Nvidia*) then tried to install an old driver (Nvidia driver 340) but after rebooting the system was unable to boot up so removed driver and now I feel frustrated because I don't know what to do.
I have MSI GE60 laptop with the following specifications:
CPU:i7 3630QM
GPU:Nvidia GTX660M
RAM:8 GB

Comment: In future instead of using your camera to take a screenshot, use `Alt`+`PrintScreen` key combination.

Comment: Try install the prop driver from NVIDIA official website.

Comment: I tried that,didn't work

Comment: With Ubuntu 18.04, I had critical problems with an Nvidia Quadro 410 card. Nvidia Quadro 600 is working well. Previously I tried the Nvidia Quadro 410 with Fedora 23 with Nvidia driver, that was working well, but only with one graphics card, not with two cards. You can try direct contact with Nvidia support, they should be able to help, it might take a couple of days to get it sorted out though.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest installing the latest NVIDIA driver through apt package manager.

To do this, you would add the graphics driver PPA with the following commands in terminal:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

After this, you should now remove any current NVIDIA drivers by entering the following into your terminal:

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

Now that you have done this, it is safe to install the latest version:

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-396`

Please note that it is nvidia-driver-396 on Ubuntu 18.04, it is nvidia-396 on Ubuntu 16.04 but you are not using 16.04.